# Unable to run my program using JETTY

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am finding it difficult to run my project on Jetty. I am following the [following tutorial so all codes are obtained from it](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/11/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example.html). The steps i took to run my project is as follows;

1.)  I wrote the following command `mvn clean install` on the project C:\Web\Spring3HibernateMaven (This is where my project is held)

2.) Opened a new console, and browsed to `C:\Web\Spring3HibernateMaven` and typed `mvn jetty:run`.

3.) i got the following message so that means Jetty is up and running.  `2011-11-23 20:51:51.997:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server`

4.) I typed `http://localhost:8080` on my web browser and i ended up with the following message

> Error 404 - Not Found.
>     No context on this server matched or handled this request.
>     Contexts known to this server are:
>     /Spring3HibernateMaven --->     org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@48bc64{/Spring3HibernateMaven,F:\VERNANJ   -Web\Spring3HibernateMaven\src\main\webapp}
>
> The above is a hyper link and when i click on it i get the following
>   message; HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /Spring3HibernateMaven/.
>   Reason:
>       NOT_FOUND Powered by Jetty:/

What should do to get this program up and running ?

**EDIT**

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/  XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven- v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Spring3HibernateMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring3HibernateMaven</artifactId>
   <name>abc</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.156</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jetty -->
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-management</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java EE 6 STACK [Persistence] -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax</groupId>
       <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
       <version>6.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warName>abc</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Jetty -->
                    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I have included my pom.xml as an edit.

Comment: The controller in the linked example uses a RequestMapping for the path `/index`, including the context that would be `/Spring3HibernateMaven/index`. Can you try to open that path in your browser?

Comment: I get a `    Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
` exception. Can you tell me what is the role of `index` because i have a `index.jsp` file and it just displays `hello world`.

Comment: Am i missing a JDBC dependency in the pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the comments in the article you mentioned, it looks like the project is missing files (list.html - which should be the welcome file). This is probably why you are receiving a 404.

Comment: I added `<welcome-file>contact.jsp</welcome-file>` to the web.xml so the first screen would be the welcome.jsp page. but i am still getting the 404 message. Any clue?

Comment: contact.jsp <> welcome.jsp - are you sure you have this correct?

Comment: i don't have a welcome.jsp so i included a contact.jsp. Is this correct?

Comment: Where is your contact.jsp located in your folder structure?

Comment: WEB-INF/jsp/contact.jsp <--- in this structure and i accessed it with http://localhost:8080/Spring3HibernateMaven/contact.jsp

Comment: Welcome files are typically in the root of your webapp folder. Try placing an welcome.html file here and changing your web.xml to reference the welcome.html file.